# elementary OS not starting from GRUB

Tags: dual-boot

I already had Windows 10 on my 128 SSD and I did partition about 230 GB from my 1TB hard drive where I installed elementary OS. Installation was successful and there were no problems.

At start GRUB shows three options: start elementary OS, start elementary OS in recovery mode (or safe mode, do not remember) and start Windows 10. Everytime I try to start elementary OS it shows only the start screen with the elementary logo and then it restarts computer. If I start it in recovery mode, it succesfully starts but I would like to use it in normal mode. Windows 10 works fine. I am quite new to Linux so I have not found solution by myself. Help me, please.

Update:
Like Suici Doga said, I removed "quiet splash" line from the kernel parameters. Then it started and I updated. Now it starts normally.

Comment: Can you start the system while holding down shift. Select your kernel and press `e`. Then remove `quiet splash` from the kernel parameters. This will allow you to see the boot output. Add the boot output to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Funny, but it started like it needed to be when I removed that "quiet splash" line. Then I updated my EOS and now it works. Do not know why. Much thanks for this!

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer. Can you mark it as answer (so it will be my first answer :)

Comment: I think it was your graphics drivers. Anyways it's fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you start the system while holding down shift. Select your kernel and press e. Then remove quiet splash from the kernel parameters. This will allow you to see the boot output.